# Can I change the browser URL while maintaining ViewState in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I'm doing some brainstorming for a portal framework, and I'm envisioning a breadcrumb navigation stack that is tracked via the ViewState (so that if the user clicks "back" in their browser and clicks some other link, the breadcrumb trail will depart from the right page).  My pages are really just ascx controls that get loaded into a placeholder control on the main portal page based on the URL.  When the user clicks a portal link, there is a postback that loads the original page and invokes the given link's "clicked" handler, which should then "push" the current location onto the breadcrumb stack before sending the browser a redirect instruction to change the URL to that of the page that I want to go to.

That's as far as my brainstorming goes for the moment, because once we perform a redirect, we lose the ViewState.  Rather than doing the redirect, I've thought of simply telling my main portal page to replace the current page control with the target page control, thus avoiding the extra http round-trip and allowing me to keep the ViewState.  But then my entire website experience occurs in the context of a single URL, so I lose URL bookmarking among other things.  And if I wrap some of my controls in AJAX panels, the entire site happens in one page request as far as the browser's history is concerned.

What I would like is some way to have the browsing history and URLs behave as if each link is leading them to a new page with a descriptive URL and all that, but still have some way to know the path that the user took to get to the page that they're on (ViewState seeming to be the simplest way to track this).

Could anyone suggest some techniques I might try using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First suggestion... You may want to look into ASP.NET MVC.  However, I have to admit to some ignorance here as I'm not sure that would really solve your problem.  But it *sounds* like the sort of thing MVC would be suited for.

Second... it's possible to override the methods responsible for saving and loading ViewState.  One of the things you can do, for instance, is push the ViewState into the Session rather than sending it down to the user and back up on postback.  You could easily add some custom code here.

Third... I think you may want to rethink part of your design.  The ViewState really serves one purpose: It recreates the state of the page as it existed when the page was rendered for the user.  If you are moving to a different page, or a new set of controls, why would you need the ViewState at all?  The ViewState itself is really just a hack to begin with... ASP.NET's way of maintaining state on top of a stateless system. (but that's a whole 'nother discussion)  We have other methods of maintaining state... the primary mechanism being the Session object.  Why not save your breaacrumb data there instead?

Comment: "(so that if the user clicks "back" in their browser and clicks some other link, the breadcrumb trail will depart from the right page)."  Maintaining state on top of a stateless system is exactly what I'm going for.  Let's say you open a link in a new tab, follow that path a few links down, and then return to your previous tab and start browsing from there.  Storing this data entirely on the session would make scenarios like this merge breadcrumbs, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using cookies.  For performance reasons, you really want to avoid HTTP redirects if you can, and ViewState only works if the user submits a form, not for regular links.

You might do something like maintain several path lists in cookies that show the path that the user took to go from one page to another.  Maybe you set a unique ID with each page that is applied by some JavaScript as a query string when the user clicks on a link, and the server uses that ID and the past history from the cookies to determine how to render the bread crumb on the next page?